# Call diconnection not working in android Oreo

Tags: android

I created a call blocking application, which disconnects a call.
I used the below function:

```
private void disconnectPhoneItelephony(Context context) {
        ITelephony telephonyService;
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
            telephonyService.endCall();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This was working fine! 
But after a security patch update it doesnt works!
What will i do. is there any solution?

Comment: After which security patch? Can you share more details?

Comment: @VicJordan May 5